# Load an external file using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, google-ad-manager

I would like to load an external file using javascript. I'm planning to add ad codes in the external file and include it using javascript wherever necessary. This will help me to change ad codes easily when the need arises.

Also I believe various third party solutions such as Google Admanager are complex and unnecessary. So I need your suggestion for the same.

Note : The external file may contain PHP / Javascript source.

What I thought was to add something like this ...

```
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='ad1.js'></script>");
```

What's your opinion ?

Comment: Is the external file on or off the server?

Comment: are you opposed to jQuery?  load();

Comment: make it whatever you want (text, xml, js) and just ajax it over

Comment: @JeffreySweeney It is available on the same server but in different subdomain such as ads.domain.com

Comment: @tq No, Jquery is ok but will it work in mobile version of website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you want to display ad codes separate from the content of the page (such as in iframes). Most ad providers don't like this, since the ads displayed won't be relevant to site content.

Another way to do it however (that makes everyone happy) is to use php's `include` statement and include the external file. This will dump the contents of the page into the current page, so make sure you don't have multiple `<html>` elements or inaccurate paths.

Comment: I didn't notice that yes many ad solutions restrict such method. So do I have any other method other then php include ?

Comment: For the ad guys, php's `include` is ok, because the site content is with the ad. My website's been using it for almost a year, and Google AdSense hasn't complained.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use document.write, is that would overwrite the content already on the page, thus making your solution quite static. Try this instead:

```
function addScript(src) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = src;

  document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

You'll want to make sure that the page has loaded enough that the document.head is defined. You could use an event listener for this.